# want to print "\n" sign without getting a new line

Tags: python, newline

I have a list and want to print the elements of the list when there is "\n" sign between them, without getting a new line between the elements.
for example : `(2) h:m:s a: Hi\n(3) h:m:s b: Bye`
I wrote this:

```
def foo(content):
    ret = []
    for massage in content:
        ret.append(str(massage))
        ret.append("\n")
    ret = ret[:-1] 
    return ''.join(ret)
```

but I get a new line between the elements...

What can I do to get the "\n" sign instead of a new line?

Comment: try with a raw string : `r"\n"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An alternative to the raw string solution is to escape the newline character

`ret.append("\\n")`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a raw string:

```
ret.append(r"\n")
```

or escape the slash:

```
ret.append("\\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use raw string by prepending the string with:

```
r'\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to escape the current "\". So instead use "\\n" because the first \ will escape second leaving python to print it as a regular character.

For example if you used "\\\n" then the first \ would escape the second leaving it as a normal character, thus printing a newline since the "\" before the n would not be escaped. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: This is incorrect; if you use "\\n", "\n" will be printed, not a newline.

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo; their mark-up stuff confused me :(